# iPhone/iPod/iPad performance tuning

Tags: iphone, performance, ipad, ios

What resources you use when you are working on iPhone/iPad application performance tuning?
Please include resources related to Quartz Graphics, OpenGL ES, Core Animation, Database management.

**Update** And guys, please do not link to Instruments, thank you.
**Update 2** Some more resources for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

I strongly recommend you these iTunes U classes.

- [Advanced iPhone Development - Spring
  2010 - 13. Performance tuning](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/13-performance-tuning/id407243032?i=89378871)
- [Advanced iPhone Development - Fall
  2010 - 11. Performance tuning](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/11-performance-tuning/id407243028?i=89378852)

Comment: Thank you Kazuki, I like the material you provided. Anyway I am waiting for much more responses for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Instruments, primarily.

logging - NSLog()

older hardware - iPhone 3G